# Marcar el paso visible en slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Quisiera saber si alguien sabia como marcar la opción que está visible en la navegación a la ahora que pasa en `autoplay` el `slider`,

Les comparto mi codigo:

```
$('.pasos[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

  var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
  $('.slidertuto').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });


$('.slidertuto').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrow:false,
  autoplay:true

});
```

Comment: Al parecer esto no es una pregunta, si no el compartir su codigo de como hacer para marcar la opción que está visible en la navegación..., ahora si colocas un ejemplo de cómo esta funciona en un contexto general quedaría mejor!!... de todas formas gracias por compartir tu código!! ;))...

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la imagen actual tienes el método `slickCurrentSlide`

```
// Get the current slide
var currentSlide = $('.your-element').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
```

Además, al `div` con la imagen activa se le añade la clase `slick-active`.

```
<div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 560px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00"><h3>1</h3></div>
```

[Fuente](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)